# How create transparent seamles texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, transparency

Somebody know how may I create my own transparent texture like this:
[image]
And once i have created it, how I have to set up the shader editor?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The desired result is not clear. Can you describe what kind of texture are looking to create? Otherwise you can also upload more reference images.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the 3D effect of bump and relief through a graphic made in 2D, and than make it transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to have a node setup like this one below for having a PNG image acting like a bump generator and having it transparent (check the transparent node and the mix shader controlled by the alpha channel of the image node):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help sanbaldo but is not what i'm locking for.